# sshd: segfault at 8 ip error 4 in libc-2.19.so on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ssh, connection, openssh

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and yesterday I was setup the reinstall openssh-server and setup goeip which allow/deny ssh access country wise. In */var/log/message* , Continuously getting below error:

```
$ tail _/var/log/message_
...
Jul 26 11:42:23 ubuntu vmunix: [436036.421573] sshd[29389]: segfault at 8 ip 00007fa3488b4c2a sp 00007ffda1a9b498 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[7fa34881d000+1ba000]
...

# sshd  -T
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 87: Unsupported option UsePAM
port 22
protocol 2
addressfamily any
listenaddress 0.0.0.0:22
listenaddress [::]:22
serverkeybits 768
logingracetime 120
keyregenerationinterval 3600
x11displayoffset 10
maxauthtries 6
maxsessions 10
clientaliveinterval 0
clientalivecountmax 3
permitrootlogin yes
ignorerhosts yes
ignoreuserknownhosts no
rhostsrsaauthentication no
hostbasedauthentication no
hostbasedusesnamefrompacketonly no
rsaauthentication yes
pubkeyauthentication yes
passwordauthentication yes
kbdinteractiveauthentication no
challengeresponseauthentication no
printmotd no
printlastlog yes
x11forwarding yes
x11uselocalhost yes
strictmodes yes
tcpkeepalive yes
permitemptypasswords no
permituserenvironment no
uselogin no
compression delayed
gatewayports no
usedns yes
allowtcpforwarding yes
useprivilegeseparation yes
pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
xauthlocation /usr/bin/xauth
loglevel INFO
syslogfacility AUTH
authorizedkeysfile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
acceptenv LANG
acceptenv LC_*
subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
maxstartups 10:100:10
permittunnel no
ipqos lowdelay throughput
permitopen any

# cat /etc/hosts.deny
sshd: ALL

# cat /etc/hosts.allow
sshd: ALL: aclexec /usr/local/bin/sshfilter.sh %a
```

Note: SSH Filtering not working!, Yesterday night it was working.

Have you anyone have any idea, Why getting this error?

Comment: How exactly did you *"setup the reinstall openssh-server"*?

Comment: @steeldriver I just reinstall `apt-get  install --reinstall openssh-server `, Can you know that why this error occur and what says this error?

Comment: No sorry - it's really hard to determine exactly what the error means: see [Interpreting segfault messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549214/interpreting-segfault-messages). Have you modified your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file? There seem to be some missing things from your sshd -T output (ciphers, kexalgorithms) and the `Unsupported option UsePAM` seems strange to me.

Comment: @steeldriver I used default _sshd_config file_ !!!